# Перетащить элемент из одного ListBox'a в другой

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется 4 ListBox, из трех которых можно перетаскивать и кидать элементы в четвертый, причем не перемещать, а копировать.
Как прописать события принимающему ListBox? события ListBox, из которых таскать, прописал. из одного ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listhelmets" Height="214"  Width="248"
 ItemsSource="{Binding ListHelmets}" 
 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Canvas.Left="464"Canvas.Top="37" 
 PreviewMouseDown="helmet_MouseDown1" 
 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="helmet_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"    
 DragLeave="helmet_DragLeave"
 PreviewMouseMove="helmet_PreviewMouseMove" 
 SelectedValuePath="protection">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Width="56"      Height="61"/>
                <TextBox Height="30" Width="30">
                  <Binding Path="protection" />
                   </TextBox>
               </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

в этот:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listHero" Height="148" Width="158" 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

для первого ListBox:

```
     private void helmet_MouseDown1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs  e)
    {
      _startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);


      }
    private void helmet_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
    if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
    Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;
    if (Math.Abs(diff.X) <= SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance
     && Math.Abs(diff.Y) <= SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        return;
    var lst = sender as ListBox;
    var li = FindAnchestor<ListBoxItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
    Console.WriteLine("move " + li);
    if (li == null) return;
    var str = lst.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(li);
    var data = new DataObject("txt", str);
    var res = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(li, data, DragDropEffects.All);
    if (res == DragDropEffects.Move)
        (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Remove(str);
     }
             static T FindAnchestor<T>(DependencyObject current) where T :  DependencyObject
{
       do
    {
        if (current is T) return (T)current;
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    while (current != null);
    return null;
}
     UPDATE  private void listHero_Drop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
 {
           var o = e.Data.GetData("txt");
     var lst = sender as ListBox;
    (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Add(o);
     e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
 }

     private void ListHero_OnDragEnter(object sender,    System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("txt"))
     e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
 }`
```

Answer (score 4):

> как прописать события принимающему листбоксу?

в xaml добавить Drop и DragEnter

```
<ListBox Drop="ListBox_Drop" DragEnter="ListBox_DragEnter" />
```

в cs добавить код обработчиков событий, примерно такой:

```
void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
   var o = e.Data.GetData(...) as ...;
   ... 
   e.Effects = DragDropEffects....;
}
void ListBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) { 
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(...))
      e.Effects = DragDropEffects....;
}
```

Код, который должен быть в обработчиках есть в примере [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/477112/3).

---

UPDATE: [v1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/478351/3), перетаскивание строк -- заменил на следующий.
UPDATE: v2, перетаскивания объектов разного типа.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="300" Height="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}" Height="100"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="DragList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
            PreviewMouseMove="DragList_PreviewMouseMove"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}" 
            Drop="ListBox_Drop" DragEnter="ListBox_DragEnter" 
            Background="LightYellow" Height="200"
            AllowDrop="True" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
interface IData { }
class Data1 : IData { 
   public override string ToString() { return "Data1"; }}
class Data2 : IData { 
   public override string ToString() { return "Data2"; }}

partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        Items1 = new ObservableCollection<object>() { new Data1(), new Data2() };
        Items2 = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Items1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items2 { get; set; }

    Point startPoint;
    void DragList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    }
    void DragList_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;
        if (Math.Abs(diff.X) <= SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance
         && Math.Abs(diff.Y) <= SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            return;
        var lst = sender as ListBox;
        var li = FindAnchestor<ListBoxItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
        Console.WriteLine("move " + li);
        if (li == null) return;
        var o = lst.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(li);
        var data = new DataObject(typeof(IData), o);
        var res = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(li, data, DragDropEffects.All);
        if (res == DragDropEffects.Move)
            (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Remove(o);
    }

    void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        var o = e.Data.GetData(typeof(IData));
        var lst = sender as ListBox;
        (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Add(o);
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    void ListBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(IData)))
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    static T FindAnchestor<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject {
        do {
            if (current is T) return (T)current;
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }
        while (current != null);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: это понятно, но что в теле просписать?

Comment: @NickShepard _"что в теле просписать?"_ -- добавил в ответ. и ссылку на работающий пример.

Comment: заменил Canvas в примере на Listbox, после этого отвалилось  var p = e.GetPosition(c);
        // ListBox.SetLeft(img, p.X);
        // ListBox.SetTop(img, p.Y);
        // c.Children.Insert(0, img); потому что у листбокса нет таких методов. но элемент перемещается из первого листбокса, исчезает, значит, переместилось, надо полагать! а как сделать, чтобы во втором листбоксе картинка появилась и ее было видно? @Stack

Comment: @NickShepard добавил код в ответ.

Comment: все проще, если это string, а у меня три разных класса в трех листбоксах - Helmet, Weapon и Armature  с соответствующей картиной и интовым свойством - каждый листбокс биндится к коллекции и принимающий листбокс должен все эти элементы типов мочь принимать @Stack

Comment: @NickShepard _"листбокс должен оба эти класса мочь принимать"_ -- значит в ListBox_Drop будет не `as string`, а проверка типов  Weapon и Armature

Comment: а если в helmet_PreviewMouseMove i write var data = new DataObject("Helmet", str); и в listHero_Drop я написал var str = e.Data.GetData("Helmet") as Helmet; var lst = sender as ListBox; (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Add(str); у меня nullreferenceexceprion здесь -  ItemsSource as IList @Stack

Comment: @NickShepard _"написал var str = e.Data.GetData("Helmet") ... у меня nullreferenceexceprion"_ -- чтобы Helmet получить, его надо сперва передать. но лучше просто проверить при получении данных. добавил второй update в ответ.

Comment: посмотрите мой обновленный вопрос @Stack

Comment: после var h = (Helmet) o; -- должен быть код для работы с h. тоже самое для остальных. а иначе switch вообще не нужен. т.е. надо просто убрать switch целиом с case'ами, а остальное оставить как есть.

Comment: если убрать, то как он будет типы различать? и как тогда написать Посмотрите обновленный вопрос и еще он ругается на "не указывает а экземпляр объекта" switch (o.GetType().Name) @Stack

Comment: @NickShepard  _"если убрать, то как он будет типы различать?"_  -- вы пробовали убрать switch? попробуйте. _"еще он ругается"_ -- т.к. в строке new DataObject("Helmet", str); должен быть txt, а не Helmet.

Comment: попробовал, но думаю, неправильно снова вас понял. снова обновил @Stack

Comment: _"обновил"_ -- вот тут e.Data.GetDataPresent("Helmet") -- вместо Helmet должно быть txt,  txt -- это как наклейка на коробке на складе магазина. если у кладовщика в бумажке написно товар txt, то он пройдет мимо коробки где написано Helmet, даже если в коробке лежит этот Helmet. просто посмотрите мой пример. везде где написано txt оставьте его, или везде (!) замените txt на любое другое слово. а также в строке e.Data.GetData("txt") as string; просто уберите as string

Comment: то есть сейчас должно работать? он все равно в этой строке (lst.ItemsSource as IList).Add(o); говорит,  что Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. @Stack

Comment: а можете помочь, как под элементы собственных классов переделать? @Stack

Comment: @NickShepard _"как под элементы собственных классов переделать?"_ -- interface IData {} добавить в свой код. и добавить его в классы так: class Helmet : IData ... class Weapon : IData ....

Comment: а что там прописывать? @Stack

Comment: @NickShepard _"а что там прописывать?"_ -- у вас Helmet и Weapon - это классы? если да, то было class Helmet {...} сделайте class Helmet : IData {...}. для остальных также.